# IupLua - Posicionar componente

Tags: lua, iup

No  IUPLua, como faço para posicionar um componente indicando o X(posição horizontal) e Y(posição vertical)?
Li na documentação:

> It will be changed during the layout computation, except when
>   FLOATING=YES or when used inside a concrete layout container.

Então tentei:

```
require "iuplua"
button = iup.button{title="button", floating="yes", position = "50,0"}
dlg = iup.dialog{title="test", size="QUARTERxQUARTER", button}

dlg:show()

iup.MainLoop()
```

Mas não muda nada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que seria "x w y"?

Comment: Corrigi na pergunta.

Comment: Pelo que está escrito na documentação que você apresentou não é para fazer nada. Você sabe inglês? Traduzindo "Ele será alterado durante a computação do layout, **exceto** quando FLOATING=YES ou quando usado dentro de um container de layout concreto.". veja: http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/en/attrib/iup_floating.html Será que o problema não é justamente ter usado este atributo?

Comment: Já tentei, com floating="no", e sem adicionar o atributo, e mesmo assim não funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `FLOATING` é um atributo processado apenas pelas caixas de layout abstrato, tais como `vbox` e `hbox`. Por isso o seu código não funcionou. No seu exemplo, fazendo `, iup.vbox{button}}` passa a funcionar.

Se você quer fazer layout concreto com IUP então o melhor é usar o `iup.cbox` como *container*. Nesse caso o exemplo deve ser modificado assim:

```
floating="yes", cx = 50} 

, iup.cbox{button}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consegui.
Para conseguir posicionar, tive que colocar o botão dentro de um box(usei hbox), e definir o atributo FLOATING do botão como "yes". Segue como ficou o código:

```
require "iuplua"
button = iup.button{title="button", floating="yes", position = "50,0"}
dlg = iup.dialog{title="test", size="QUARTERxQUARTER", iup.hbox{button}}

dlg:show()

iup.MainLoop()
```

Ficou assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu ia comentar sobre isto também, estava lendo a documentação e vi que precisa do container. Agora você pode escolher a sua resposta ou a do autor da biblioteca :)